# How to give a new variable to all the threads?

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets, server

I made a program that resembles a game's chat where players can talk, the server owner can broadcast a message (From the server's machine).

So the code till now is this:

```
import socket
import threading

HEADER = 64
PORT = 5050
SERVER = "192.168.0.100"
ADDR = (SERVER, PORT)
FORMAT = 'utf-8'
DISCONNECT_MESSAGE = "!DISCONNECT"

server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server.bind(ADDR)

def handle_client(conn, addr):
    print(f"[NEW CONNECTION] {addr} connected.")

    connected = True
    while connected:
        msg_lenght = conn.recv(HEADER).decode(FORMAT)
        if msg_lenght:
            msg_lenght = int(msg_lenght)
            msg = conn.recv(msg_lenght).decode(FORMAT)
            if msg == DISCONNECT_MESSAGE:
                connected = False

            else:
                print(f"[{addr}] {msg}")
    
    conn.close()

def start():
    server.listen()
    print(f"[LISTENING] Sever is listening on {SERVER}")
    while True:
        conn, addr = server.accept()
        thread = threading.Thread(target=handle_client, args=(conn, addr))
        thread.start()
        print(f"[ACTIVE CONNECTIONS] {threading.activeCount() - 1}")

print("[STARTING] Starting......")
start()
```

This is the server side code. I am fining difficulty in adding the part where the server owner can broadcast a message. (I din't add the part where the players can  talk privately too)

So my question is that how can I differentiate between clients?

Comment: The address tuple returned by "socket.accept" is different for each client.

Comment: ohh, I missed that detail prolly, thanks for telling me that, could you put that as answer so I can tick it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple way is to pass a mutable container as a parameter to the `handle_client` function, and have it to contain all the active connections. At the minimum you could use a list containing the connected sockets and protect it with a mutex:

```
lock = threading.Lock()

def handle_client(conn, addr, connections):
    print(f"[NEW CONNECTION] {addr} connected.")
    with lock:
        connections.append(conn)
    ...
    conn.close()
    with lock
        connections.remove(conn)

def start():
    server.listen()
    print(f"[LISTENING] Sever is listening on {SERVER}")
    connections = []
    while True:
        conn, addr = server.accept()
        thread = threading.Thread(target=handle_client, args=(conn, addr, connections))
```

That way, in handle client you have a list of all the active connections and that list can be use to broadcast a message.

If you want to easily allow users to exchange messages, you could also give a unique id to each connection, and use that id as a key to a `connections` dictionary.

Comment: what does Lock() do?

Comment: And if I have to broadcast a message how will I do so? Like do I start a new thread for it? (But this makes it so that if ```connections``` gets any new ```conn``` then it wont be able to get the improved version of ```connections```) Or just create a new client with the permissions as admin? (but that wont help me improve my coding skills)

Answer (score 0):

When calling

```
conn, addr = server.accept()
```

The returned `addr` for an IP-based network is a tuple consisting of the IP-address or domain name of the client, the port number used on client for connection and maybe further data.

The tuple contents are unique for a specific client connection and can be used to distinguish the connections.